# tkinter не выводит текст в терминал рядом с графиком

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Хочу подписать оси графика в терминале, но текст не выводится на экран. Из-за малого опыта не выходит решить проблему самому.

```
#прога для вычисления новой осадки после принятия балласта
from math import *                #Библиотеки
from tkinter import *             #Библиотеки
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   #Библиотеки

tk=Tk()
print ("Если число нецелочисленное,\nто после целой части числа ставится точка вместо запятой. \nПример - 17.88; 6.717.") #Вывод текста на экран. \n - отступ на нов строку
## Здесь был ввод данных импорт
##########
L=120;   #
B=17.88; #
H=6.717; #
T=5.027; #
##########
canvas=Canvas(tk,height =(L/2)*12, width=(L+B+300)*4)                    #размеры терминала
canvas.configure (background='light goldenrod')                          #цвет терминала
canvas.pack ()                                                           #команда на создание окна терминала
kx=-0.76;                                                                #коэфф. для уравнивания Х с Y (У меня была дробная часть, которая мне нафиг не сдалась)
ky=25;                                                                   #коэфф. для уравнивания Y с х (Y был меня х на 50). Для равенства осей. Межете тупо их занулить, если не нужны.
x0=25;y0=25;xm=((L+B+300)*2)-250+kx;ym=5*L;                              #Координаты для позиционирования графиков,текста на экране

#1-й график (и расчётные формулы)
#Оси
def coord (x0,y0,xm,ym,fil_color):
 canvas.create_line(x0,(ym-y0)/2,xm,(ym-y0)/2,fill=fil_color,arrow=LAST) #Позиционирование ОХ, фил - цвет, арров - где ставить стрелку на прямой (ласт - конец, фирст - начало)
 canvas.create_line(xm/2,y0-ky,xm/2,ym-25+ky,fill=fil_color,arrow=FIRST) #Позиционирование ОУ
                                       
 
#Заголовки ОХ и ОУ
canvas.create_text(xm-150,(((ym-y0)/2)-300),text="Аварийная Ватерлиния",fill="black")

coord (x0,y0,xm,ym,'black')                                              #Цвет осей    
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
label = tk.Label(root,text ='TEXT')
label.place(relx = 0.0, rely = 1.0)
```

(`relx` и `rely` заменить на подходящее)